# clang fails to compile with boost::rational

Tags: c++, boost, clang++

The following code

```cpp
#include <boost/rational.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto r = boost::rational<int>{3,2};
    std::cout << r << "\n";
}
```

Compiles fine with the following `g++ -std=gnu++2b -o try try.cpp` and outputs `3/2` as expected. However with clang I get this

```
In file included from try.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/rational.hpp:69:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.1/../../../../include/c++/13.1.1/iomanip:42:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.1/../../../../include/c++/13.1.1/bits/ios_base.h:41:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.1/../../../../include/c++/13.1.1/bits/locale_classes.h:40:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.1/../../../../include/c++/13.1.1/string:48:
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.1/../../../../include/c++/13.1.1/bits/stl_iterator.h:2618:35: error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'iterator_traits<_It>::iterator_category'
      { using iterator_category = iterator_traits<_It>::iterator_category; };
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated
```

This is with clang version 15.0.7 and gcc version 13.1.1. I see from https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=100900 that similar issues were reported a couple of years ago but are fixed now. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Boost libraries are 1.81.0-6 installed in Arch linux.

Comment: That is odd.  Works on Compiler Explorer with boost 1.81 and gcc 13.1  https://godbolt.org/z/3oT3bcb5r

Comment: Yes, gcc works, clang fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update to Clang 16. [Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) says that ["Make typename more optional"](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0634r3.html) from C++20 was implemented in Clang 16, and libstdc++ 13 seems to rely on it.

Comment: thanks, this indeed seems to be the reason. I'll accept the answer when I get to check it. A little lazy to manually install when clang 16 should hit the Arch repo relatively soon.

Comment: Indeed accepting this as the right answer, tried clang 17 from git and it does compile

Answer (score 0):

That bug fix you link to was fixed by changing `libstdc++` so that it works with the `clang` compiler, because `clang` seemed to *require* the optional `typename` in the `using` declaration.

It did not fix `clang` itself so, if another library (or *any* piece of valid code) also leaves off the `typename`, `clang` will still complain.

A bug raised on `clang` is [what's needed here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues) (unless there's already a later release that fixes it, of course<sup>(1)</sup>). This will solve *all* possible occurrences of this issue rather than having to patch multiple (perfectly valid) bits of code to work around a `clang` deficiency.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Before raising a bug, you should try `clang` 16 to see if it's still an issue. Although the release notes seem to indicate fixes for only `using enum`, there may have been unannounced work done there as well.

Comment: The error seems to be coming from the stl itself, not boost, I posted this example cause it's the same path that triggered for me